# A game for a Raspberry Pi to be played with bananas

Tags: game, raspberry-pi

I want to use the following materials for animations with kids:

- A Raspberry Pi 3 model B running Ubuntu Mate
- A 17 inches screen with 1600x900 resolution
- A [Makey Makey](http://makeymakey.com/) and a few alligator clips
- Bananas as controller for the Makey Makey

As such, I am searching for a game for them to play.
This game must fulfil these requirements:

- Use simple-to-understand mechanics (think Pacman level)
- Fairly basic control-wise:

  - The controls allowed with bananas are:

    - <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> keys and <kbd>left-click</kbd> (simple ones)
    - <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> (wiring a wee bit more complicated)
    - <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> for the pointer and both clicks (controls way harder than with an actual mouse)
  - As such, the game should be fully controllable with only the above keys. Rebinding is okay.
  - Due to the nature of pointer controls, games which are simple to play with an actual mouse can become very challenging when using the Makey Makey.
- The game must be able to run on a Pi, although not necessarily at full resolution.

What would also be great is:

- If the game was Open-Source
- If it had some kind of local (one screen) multi-player, or even LAN multi-player

Comment: There is [another question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/26133/24316) on this topic, but it did not provide any control information.

Comment: Throwing bomberman in here, no information on open-source though. But it does have a LAN multiplayer :D

Comment: `bomberclone` on the universe repository works nicely yep!

Answer (score 3):

[SuperTux](https://supertuxproject.org/), a free clone of Super Mario Bros.

- It runs on the Raspberry Pi
- It uses the keys, the space bar and CTRL to shoot
- Simply to understand mechanics. I think everybody knows how to play Super Mario
- It doesn't have network support
- But it comes with a map editor. However you will need a mouse to design a map.

[image: SuperTux]

Comment: Interesting. The keys can be rebound, so I can plug the action key to a banana too. I'll have to check how nicely the game runs on a Pi though, a 3 minutes search [brought this video](https://youtu.be/IEqZDHZtnrg) of someone successfully using a Pi to play the game back in 2012.